How to change the pagelanguage of google translate api in javascript?
i need to change pagelanguage of google translate element. For example : 
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en'},'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

As you see here the pagelanguage of the translateElement is english. How can i change it to something else in the project.

The previous dupe was getting the language, not setting it

If you want to just change the FROM language, you need to modify the {pageLanguage: 'en'} before loading the script that calls the function
For example
https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6ugh4nt5/
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<div>
  Denne side er Dansk.
</div>

<script defer>
  const lang = 'da'; // danish
  function googleTranslateElementInit() {
    new google.translate.TranslateElement({
      pageLanguage: lang,
      includedLanguages: 'en',
      autoDisplay: true
    }, 'google_translate_element');
  };


  const script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = 'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit';
  document.querySelector('head').appendChild(script);
</script>


If you want to translate when the page loads, you can do this
You need to hide a few elements and use setTimeout to defer the translation
Code is a modification of Translate website to any specific language, on page load
This will translate the english page to danish
NOTE: This snippet does not run at SO. Try the fiddle instead
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    includedLanguages: 'da',
    autoDisplay: false
  }, 'google_translate_element');
  setTimeout(() => {
    var a = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select");
    a.selectedIndex = 1;
    a.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }, 1000)
}

<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" defer src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<div>
Now is the time for all men to come to the aid of their country
</div>

